# Scala -jline file completer causes file not found (linux)

Tags: scala, jline

I'm seeing something very bizarre in this piece of code.

```
    command match {
      case "q" | "quit" =>  done=true
      case "f" | "file" =>
        {
//        console_reader.addCompleter(fn_completer)
          val f:String=console_reader.readLine("input filename >")
          val filename=
            if(java.nio.file.Paths.get(f).isAbsolute())
              f
            else
              System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+f
          val ft=Paths.get(filename).toString()
          console_reader.println(ft)
          if(Files.exists(Paths.get(filename))) 
            process_file(filename)
          else
            console_reader.println(filename+" does not exist")
//        console_reader.removeCompleter(fn_completer)
    }
  case _ => console_reader.println(command+" not a command")
}
```

when I run and type build.sbt everything is fine--process_file is called.
When I uncomment  the file completer lines, the same file is reported as not existing. What's up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the line, place `console_reader.println(":"+f+":")`
and it becomes apparent that with the completer and using tab completion, a space is appended to the filename.

I changed the line to `val f=console_reader.readLine("input filename >").stripLineEnd.trim()` and that fixed things.